# How can one use Active Directory authentication without requiring the user to enter a domain name?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, login-control

Right now I have Active Directory authentication working on a web application. Users login with their AD credentials. They have to enter their ad credentials like:

> myname@ourdomain.com

I'd like for them to be able to enter their ad credentials like:

> myname

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You have to show some of your authentication code.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Forms Authentication?  If you're using Windows, then there's nothing you can do.  If you're using Forms with an AD provider, then you can simply check to see if the user typed in the domain, and if not add it before you validate the password.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did as a work around

change your login control into template

and then add this code

```
 Protected Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If Not UCase(LoginUser.UserName).EndsWith("@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL") Then
        LoginUser.UserName &= "@MYDOMAIN.local"
    End If
End Sub
```

OR

on your web.config add :

```
       attributeMapUsername="SAMAccountName" to your provider
```

so it looks like

```
 <membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add
       name="MyADMembershipProvider"
       type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
       connectionUsername="MYDOMAIN\administrator"
       connectionPassword="MYPASSWORD"
       enableSearchMethods="true"
       attributeMapUsername="SAMAccountName"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```